# $node variable for categories (taxonomy) url?

Tags: nodes

I have this structure in a node-- template so I have access to the node properties:

```
<a href="#" title="<?php print $category ?>"><?php print $category ?></a>
```

I also can

```
dpm($node);
```

Can someone tell me what is the variable that prints category url? Categories are listes as /category/category_name in address bar.

Thanks